# How to pause simple canvas game, made with js and html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a simple snake game after following some simple tutorials on YouTube.

The problem is that the game does not have a pause function (e.g. when pressing P the game should pause/resume) and when the snake hits the border of the canvas the game restarts itself (but that is another problem).

Here is the complete code I have of the game: https://pastebin.com/URaDxSvF

The pause-related functions I've created:

```
function gamePaused{ /**i need help on this**/ }

function keyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 80) pauseGame();
}

function pauseGame() {
  if (!gamePaused) {
    game = clearTimeout(game);
    gamePaused = true;
  } else if (gamePaused) {
    game = setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);
    gamePaused = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Boolean variable called paused and set it to true if the player presses p, Then put an if statement around the loop that runs your game. and say if (!paused){run loop}

You can create a toggle pause function for when p is pressed.

```
function togglePause()
{
    if (!paused)
    {
        paused = true;
    } else if (paused)
    {
       paused= false;
    }

}
```

You also need to create an event listener for when p is pressed
Like this

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
var key = e.keyCode;
if (key === 80)// p key
{
    togglePause();
}
});
```

up the top where you have Game objects and constants put in paused = false, and in your loop function do this

```
 draw(); 
if(!paused)
{ 
update(); 
}
```

Comment: So I've modified the keydown function to make the variable true if it's pressed-------> paused = new Boolean(false);

function keyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 80) 
 paused = true;
 pauseGame();
}------then I've put around my loop if(!paused){ update(); draw();} i will also need and else statement to pause it, how shoud i actually do that? Thank you in advance and sorry for disturbing

Comment: Don't make a new Boolean, when p is pressed. you should initially set pause to false when you star the game and the you can toggle with p

Comment: I am currently struggling with the fac that after doing this, the canvas just stops loading...    https://pastebin.com/j7xuLE9R

Comment: up the top where you have  Game objects and constants put in paused = false, and in your loop function do this                                                
    draw();
    if(!paused)
    {
     update();
    }

Comment: Thank you! This made the rick, I am grateful for your help as this was important for me :D

Comment: Can i achieve same pause with button click rather than toggle ?

Answer (score 2):

### Game state managment

Games will usually have various game states. Pause, End game, Press key to start, etc... As the optimal way to run a game is via a single main loop the easiest way to manage game states is to have variable hold the current state function and just assign that variable the appropriate function to handle the current state.

**BTW** you should use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` or `setinterval` and `keyCode` should not be used as it is depreciated use `keyEvent.code` (see example for details)

```
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // start when code below done.
// set up keyboard IO
const keys = {
    KeyP : false,
    Enter : false,
    listener(e){
       if(keys[e.code] !== undefined){
           keys[e.code] = e.type === "keydown";
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
addEventListener("keydown",keys.listener);
addEventListener("keyup",keys.listener);

// the current game state
var currentState = startGame;

function startGame (){
    // code to do a single frame of start game
   // display press enter to start
   if(keys.Enter){
      keys.Enter = false;
      currentState = game;  // start the game
   }
}
function pause(){
    // code to do a single frame of pause
   // display pause
    if(keys.KeyP){
       keys.KeyP = false; // turn off key
       currentState = game;   // resume game
    }

}
function game(){
    // code to do a single frame of game
    if(keys.KeyP){
       keys.KeyP = false; // turn off key
       currentState = pause;  // pause game
    }
}
function mainLoop(time){
    currentState(); // call the current game state
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 1):

Your game loop is not based on `setTimeout`, but on `requestAnimationFrame`. So setting and clearing a timer will not change anything.

Secondly, you did not bind your `keyDown` function to any event, so it will never get invoked.

#### Solution:

Have a look at your `loop` function: it calls itself asynchronously, which provides the animation. You need to stop that loop to effectively introduce a pause:

```
function loop() {
    if (gamePaused) return; // <--- stop looping
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}
```

Define the new variable upon page load, and bind your function to the `keyDown` event:

```
var gamePaused = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
```

And your `pauseGame` function would look like this:

```
function pauseGame() {
    gamePaused = !gamePaused; // toggle the gamePaused value (false <-> true)
    if (!gamePaused) loop(); // restart loop
}
```

Comment: I feel like this might do the trick but i am struggling with binding the function as after defining the variables just stop loading and the page becomes blank.    https://pastebin.com/zEAJc8xw , if it's not too much could you check to see if I did it right, thank you and sorry for disturbing again

Comment: Why did you delete the `keyDown` function? You need it, it was correct. Also you mistyped `gamePaused` leaving out the last letter. And of course, that line will do nothing if it is commented out ;-)

Comment: Can you please tell what is keydown here?

Comment: @SachinHR, if this question is directed to me: for the event: see [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown). For the *function* `keyDown`: it was defined in the question.