# How to make JavaScript canvas game Pause?

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen various pages on how to pause my canvas game but I am having no luck! I have used this code now but still, nothing happens. I want to use the 'p' key to pause and then play the game.

```
        <html>
        <title>Level Selector</title>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="400"></canvas>

        <style type="text/css">
        canvas { background: #eee; }
        </style>

        <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var dx = 2;//Ball is moving in x direction at a constant rate
    var dy = -2;//Ball is moving in y direction at a constant rate
    var ballRadius = 10;//To see if ball is colliding with brick/canvas
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
    var rightPressed = false;//This variable is false because the 'right arrow' key is not pressed.
    var leftPressed = false;//This variable is false because the 'left arrow' key is not pressed.
    var brickRowCount = 5;
    var brickColumnCount = 8;
    var brickWidth = 75;
    var brickHeight = 20;
    var brickPadding = 10;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
    var score = 0;
    var lives = 3;
    var paused = false;

    var bricks = [];//this is an array holding all the bricks
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
        bricks[c] = [];
        for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
           bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };//If status is '1' then draw it. However, is status is '0', fill in with background
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);//Functions only when key is pressed
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);//Functions only when key is not pressed
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);//Functions only when mouse curcor moves


    //keyCode(39) is the code for the 'right arrow' key and keyCode(37) is the code for the 'left arrow' key
        function keyDownHandler(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                rightPressed = true;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                leftPressed = true;
            }
        }

        function keyUpHandler(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                leftPressed = false;
            }
        }


        function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
        var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;//This represents the hoizontal mouse movement.
            if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
            paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
        }
    }

        function paused{
            if (e.keyCode == 80) pauseGame();
        }

        function pauseGame{
            if (!paused)
        {
            paused = true;
        } else if (paused)
        {
           paused= false;
        }
        }

        //Collisions only true when:
        //  -The x position of the ball is greater than the x position of the brick.
        //  -The x position of the ball is less than the x position of the brick plus its width.
        //  -The y position of the ball is greater than the y position of the brick.
        //  -The y position of the ball is less than the y position of the brick plus its height.
        function collisionDetection() {
        for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
            for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
                var b = bricks[c][r];
                if(b.status == 1) {
                    if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
                        dy = -dy;
                        b.status = 0;
                        score++;
                    if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
                        alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATULATIONS!");
                        document.location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

        //this is the score variable of the game
        function drawScore() {
        ctx.font = "16px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
    }

        //this is the lives variable of the game
        function drawLives() {
        ctx.font = "16px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fillText("Lives: "+lives, canvas.width-65, 20);
    }

        //this creates the ball
        function drawBall() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        //this creates the paddle
        function drawPaddle() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        //this creates the bricks
        function drawBricks() {
        for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
            for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
                if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                    var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
                    var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
                    bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
                    bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }
    }

        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//clears canvas content from previous frame
            drawBall();//this code draws the ball onto the canvas
            drawPaddle();//this code draws the paddle onto the canvas
            collisionDetection();//this codes enables the collision detection for the ball and bricks
            drawBricks();//this code draws the bricks onto the canvas
            drawScore();//this code draws the score variable onto the canvas
            drawLives();//this code draws the lives variable onto the canvas

            //Reverse Ball movement when the ball collides with wall in 'x' direction (Left/Right wall)
            if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
            dx = -dx;
        }

            //Reverse Ball movement when the ball collides with wall in 'y' direction (Top/Bottom wall)
        if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }   else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
        if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
            dy = -dy;//If the ball collides with the paddle,  the ball is rebounded in the opposite direction.
        }
            else {
                lives--;
        if(!lives) {
            alert("GAME OVER");
            document.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                x = canvas.width/2;
                y = canvas.height-30;
                dx = 2;
                dy = -2;
                paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
            }
        }
    }

        if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {//limits paddle movement in between the canvas width
            paddleX += 7;//Paddle shifts 7 pixels in the positive x direction
        }
        else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {//limits paddle movement in between the canvas width
                paddleX -= 7;//Paddle shifts 7 pixels in the negative x direction
            }

        x += dx;//Ball is updated by painting it over each position it moves in
        y += dy;//Ball is updated by painting it over each position it moves in
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

        if(!paused)
        { 
        update(); 
        }

        </script>

        <body>


        </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, everything else about the code is good apart from the pause feature. I am completely bemused and don't know how to make it work at all. Please give a tips or a solution thanks.

EDit: I have put in a pause variable and function but its not working still.

Comment: I don't even see where `pause()` is defined. Set a variable, and if the game is paused, don't accept any more input, or draw.

Comment: Try to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814422/how-to-pause-simple-canvas-game-made-with-js-and-html5

Comment: I see where you call update() if pause is false, but I don't see the function update() defined anywhere

Comment: @FrankerZ how do you do that? Like what do I put in?

Comment: @LucasOliveira That didn't work for me

Comment: Sorry to be a dick, but you don't seem to be putting any thought into this, and you're just copy pasting in code you found on the internet. There is no paused variable in your code, and no update function. How do you expect it to work when you're referencing things that don't exist? You should try to think about your code before you come to SO asking people to write the code for you.

Comment: @ChrisRollins I know its copy and pasted since I have no idea what's going on. I get the rest of the code, just this pause thing

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner You seem to have a lot of relevant code you've left out. The concept of pause is that pause is a flag(a boolean variable that's true or false) that you can set with a keypress. Simply don't render when pause is true.

Comment: @ChrisRollins  Check out my updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove all errors appearing in your console:

1) Add a "paused" var to you code:

```
var paused = false;
```

2) Remove unnecessary code:

```
if(!paused)
{ 
update(); 
}
```

3) Your togglePause function is using a keycode var that does not exists. Change it to:

```
function togglePause() {
     paused = !paused;
     draw();
}
```

Calling the draw function will do the trick to continue the game when paused.

4) And fix the function that calls it:

```
function pauseGameKeyHandler(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        switch(keyCode){
           case 80: //p
             togglePause();
             break;
         }
}
```

5) At the end of your draw function add a test to the paused variable:

```
if(!paused) {
   requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Full code with the changes:

```
<html>
    <title>Level Selector</title>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="400"></canvas>

    <style type="text/css">
        canvas { background: #eee; }
    </style>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var x = canvas.width/2;
        var y = canvas.height-30;
        var dx = 2;//Ball is moving in x direction at a constant rate
        var dy = -2;//Ball is moving in y direction at a constant rate
        var ballRadius = 10;//To see if ball is colliding with brick/canvas
        var paddleHeight = 10;
        var paddleWidth = 75;
        var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
        var rightPressed = false;//This variable is false because the 'right arrow' key is not pressed.
        var leftPressed = false;//This variable is false because the 'left arrow' key is not pressed.
        var brickRowCount = 5;
        var brickColumnCount = 8;
        var brickWidth = 75;
        var brickHeight = 20;
        var brickPadding = 10;
        var brickOffsetTop = 30;
        var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
        var score = 0;
        var lives = 3;
        var paused = false;


        var bricks = [];//this is an array holding all the bricks
        for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
            bricks[c] = [];
            for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
                bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };//If status is '1' then draw it. However, is status is '0', fill in with background
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);//Functions only when key is pressed
        document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);//Functions only when key is not pressed
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);//Functions only when mouse curcor moves


        //keyCode(39) is the code for the 'right arrow' key and keyCode(37) is the code for the 'left arrow' key
            function keyDownHandler(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                    rightPressed = true;
                }
                else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                    leftPressed = true;
                }
            }

            function keyUpHandler(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                    rightPressed = false;
                }
                else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                    leftPressed = false;
                }
            }


            function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
                var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;//This represents the hoizontal mouse movement.
                    if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
                    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
                }
            }

            window.addEventListener('keydown', pauseGameKeyHandler, false);

            function pauseGameKeyHandler(e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode;
                switch(keyCode){
                    case 80: //p
                    togglePause();
                    break;
                }

            }

            function togglePause() {
                paused = !paused;
                draw();
            }


            //Collisions only true when:
            //  -The x position of the ball is greater than the x position of the brick.
            //  -The x position of the ball is less than the x position of the brick plus its width.
            //  -The y position of the ball is greater than the y position of the brick.
            //  -The y position of the ball is less than the y position of the brick plus its height.
            function collisionDetection() {
            for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
                for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
                    var b = bricks[c][r];
                    if(b.status == 1) {
                        if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
                            dy = -dy;
                            b.status = 0;
                            score++;
                        if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
                            alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATULATIONS!");
                            document.location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            //this is the score variable of the game
            function drawScore() {
            ctx.font = "16px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
            ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
        }

            //this is the lives variable of the game
            function drawLives() {
            ctx.font = "16px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
            ctx.fillText("Lives: "+lives, canvas.width-65, 20);
        }

            //this creates the ball
            function drawBall() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            //this creates the paddle
            function drawPaddle() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            //this creates the bricks
            function drawBricks() {
            for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
                for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
                    if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                        var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
                        var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
                        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
                        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.closePath();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//clears canvas content from previous frame
                drawBall();//this code draws the ball onto the canvas
                drawPaddle();//this code draws the paddle onto the canvas
                collisionDetection();//this codes enables the collision detection for the ball and bricks
                drawBricks();//this code draws the bricks onto the canvas
                drawScore();//this code draws the score variable onto the canvas
                drawLives();//this code draws the lives variable onto the canvas

                //Reverse Ball movement when the ball collides with wall in 'x' direction (Left/Right wall)
                if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
                dx = -dx;
            }

                //Reverse Ball movement when the ball collides with wall in 'y' direction (Top/Bottom wall)
            if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
                dy = -dy;
            }   else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
            if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
                dy = -dy;//If the ball collides with the paddle,  the ball is rebounded in the opposite direction.
            }
                else {
                    lives--;
            if(!lives) {
                alert("GAME OVER");
                document.location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    x = canvas.width/2;
                    y = canvas.height-30;
                    dx = 2;
                    dy = -2;
                    paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                }
            }
        }

            if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {//limits paddle movement in between the canvas width
                paddleX += 7;//Paddle shifts 7 pixels in the positive x direction
            }
            else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {//limits paddle movement in between the canvas width
                    paddleX -= 7;//Paddle shifts 7 pixels in the negative x direction
                }

            x += dx;//Ball is updated by painting it over each position it moves in
            y += dy;//Ball is updated by painting it over each position it moves in
            if(!paused) {
                requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            }
        }

        draw();

    </script>

    <body>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I can finally progress on this code thanks again :)

Comment: You are welcome! If your problem is solved, then please mark this as the answer to your question